# Accessing functions from parent scope in a template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to access a function from a parent scope, and even when looking at quite a few posts about this, i can't seem to find what i'm doing wrong. First off, i have a page where i'm calling the ms-card directive like this:

```
<div ng-if="vm.isPhone ? ($index < 2) : ($index < 5)" flex="50" flex-xs="50" flex-sm="33" flex-md="25" flex-gt-md="20" ng-repeat="item in vm.OffersData[val.key]">
    <ms-card template="'app/main/offers/offer-card-template/offerCardTemplate.html'" ng-model="item" view-model="vm"></ms-card>
</div>
```

Keep in mind, the item i'm sending through is doing just fine and it is showing me everything that is in there. Now this is what the directive looks like:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app.core').directive('msCard', msCardDirective);
    /** @ngInject */
    function msCardDirective() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E'
            , scope: {
                templatePath: '=template'
                , card: '=ngModel'
                , vm: '=viewModel'
            }
            , template: '<div class="ms-card-content-wrapper" ng-include="templatePath" onload="cardTemplateLoaded()"></div>'
            , compile: function (tElement) {
                // Add class
                tElement.addClass('ms-card');
                return function postLink(scope, iElement) {
                    // Methods
                    scope.cardTemplateLoaded = cardTemplateLoaded;
                    //////////
                    /**
                     * Emit cardTemplateLoaded event
                     */
                    function cardTemplateLoaded() {
                        scope.$emit('msCard::cardTemplateLoaded', iElement);
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

And finally i'm trying to call the function in the card like this:

```
<div class="media" ng-click="vm.showDetailedOffer(card.shopkey, card.key)"> <img class="image" ng-src="{{card.img}}" fallback-src onload-src> </div>
```

Any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The mistake i was making in was in the parent controller (not shown above). I defined the function showDetailedOffer as this: $scope.showDetailedOffer = function. but it should have been vm.showDetailedOffer..